# Multiple Markers Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I keep getting Multiple markers error on the code below and similarly in the readData function..

```
public static void writeData(OutputStream os) throws IOException
{
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            int random = (int)(Math.random() % 100) + 1;
            out.writeChars("Random value = " + random);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
}
```

Multiple markers means that there is more than one error ... but I can't solve the issue...

Comment: on which line did you get the error?

Comment: what are the error descriptions?